# Lazy loading (pagination) of data into DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, pagination

I am looking for a way to "lazily" load data into DataGridView (DGV for short) using NHibernate. When I open window with DGV I want it to load only part of data (e.g. 50 records), then, if user scrolls DGV down and is close to the end (or exactly at the last row) more data should be automatically loaded and inserted into DGV.

For now (I've just started working on it) I am using this simple code:

```
dgv.DataSource = session.QueryOver<T>().List();
```

It loads data, returns it as `IList<T>` and sets that as `DataSource` for my DGV. Now I want to load this data in chunks as described above, so I will use `BindingList<T>` as the `DataSource`, then add more data into that list.

At this point all I need is a way to know, when should I add more records to my BindingList. Is there any event provided by DGV, something like `NewRowNeeded` event, that would allow me to implement that functionality? Are there any other events that can help me with this task?

The obvious problem with `NewRowNeeded` event is that it requires `VirtualMode` of DGV which in turn forces me to realise the actual "binding" which in this case would be disabled. As I don't need to handle data shown in DGV in any way (other than telling: show this property in this column, end), I don't think `VirtualMode` is the right way, but actually I've never tried using this mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I've found a way to do pagination but still keep `DataSource` binding usable. It can be achieved using `Scroll` event which occurs whenever index of first shown row changes (or something like that, I haven't checked what is inside the code created by Microsoft). In handler of this event I can use `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property and `DisplayedRowCount` method to check (calculate) the index of last displayed row. Knowing that index and amount of already loaded rows I can decide when to load more data. There is one more event handler needed - `Resize`. `Scroll` event won't fire up on DGV resize, because it seems to be related (as I wrote above) to the index of first visible row, so if DGV grows in size (as a control), then last displayed row index has to be checked again.

Only downside I've found now (this is not implemented yet, just thinking of a way to solve problem) is that simple mouse scroll fires this event three times (probably depends on system settings), using scroll bar on the side would fire many more, so I'll have to find a way to load that data "gently" during scrolling (save amount of rows already requested, load data in separate thread).